# PHP: Modal dentro de un bucle toma siempre el 1er valor del bucle

Tags: php, html

He creado un modal para que, a partir de recopilatorios de 15 canciones, año a año, el usuario pueda elegir sus favoritas y crear sus propias listas personalizadas (hasta un máximo de 3) que luego exportar a YouTube.

Cada canción lleva anexo un botón (recuadro rojo), que al ser pulsado despliega el modal con las listas del usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por facilitar las cosas posteriormente desde jQuery y no tener que retrotraerme demasiado en el DOM, al array de PHP que incluye la información con las listas le he añadido el `id_cancion` correspondiente:

Si hacemos un `var_dump($listas)`:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[41]
      public 'id_lista_youtube' => string '8' (length=1)
      public 'nombre_lista' => string 'Recopilatorio 1' (length=15)
      public 'numero_canciones' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'tiempo_pasado' => string '2590' (length=4)
      public 'id_cancion' => string '196' (length=3)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[42]
      public 'id_lista_youtube' => string '9' (length=1)
      public 'nombre_lista' => string 'Recopilatorio 2' (length=15)
      public 'numero_canciones' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'tiempo_pasado' => string '1553' (length=4)
      public 'id_cancion' => string '196' (length=3)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[46]
      public 'id_lista_youtube' => string '10' (length=2)
      public 'nombre_lista' => string 'Recopilatorio 3' (length=15)
      public 'numero_canciones' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'tiempo_pasado' => string '1517' (length=4)
      public 'id_cancion' => string '196' (length=3)
```

Y así en bucle hasta 15:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[77]
      public 'id_lista_youtube' => string '8' (length=1)
      public 'nombre_lista' => string 'Recopilatorio 1' (length=15)
      public 'numero_canciones' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'tiempo_pasado' => string '2590' (length=4)
      public 'id_cancion' => string '209' (length=3)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[84]
      public 'id_lista_youtube' => string '9' (length=1)
      public 'nombre_lista' => string 'Recopilatorio 2' (length=15)
      public 'numero_canciones' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'tiempo_pasado' => string '1553' (length=4)
      public 'id_cancion' => string '209' (length=3)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[88]
      public 'id_lista_youtube' => string '10' (length=2)
      public 'nombre_lista' => string 'Recopilatorio 3' (length=15)
      public 'numero_canciones' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'tiempo_pasado' => string '1517' (length=4)
      public 'id_cancion' => string '209' (length=3)
```

Como podéis ver, la información es constante para las listas (siempre se pintan las mismas tres con la misma información al pulsar cualquiera de los quince botones), pero `id_cancion` va variando con la canción, como es lógico; la 1ª en este caso es la 196 y la 15ª, la 209.

Sin embargo, cuando intentas acceder al `id_cancion` desde jQuery, sea cual sea el modal que despliegues, siempre toma el valor de la primera canción de la lista de 15, que en este caso sería 196.

El `foreach` que pinta toda la información:

```
foreach($canciones as $clave => $fila) 
{
    $ano = $fila->ano; //Parámetros obtenidos mediante $videos->listar_todo()
    $enlace_rym = $fila->enlace_rym;
    $enlace_youtube = $fila->enlace_youtube;
    $id_autor = $fila->id_autor;
    $id_cancion = $fila->id_cancion;
    $nombre_autor = Utilidades::reordenar($fila->nombre_autor);
    $nombre_ciudad = $fila->nombre_ciudad;
    $nombre_pais = $fila->nombre_pais;
    $nota_media = Utilidades::formatear($fila->nota_media, 2);
    $tipo = Utilidades::minusculas($fila->tipo);
    $titulo_cancion = $fila->titulo_cancion;
    $titulo_disco = $fila->titulo_disco;
    $votos_web = Utilidades::formatear($fila->votos_web, 0);
    
    $nota = $fila->nota; //Parámetro obtenido mediante $usuario->listar_notas()

    $subestilos = array();
    $subestilos = $fila->subestilos; //Parámetro obtenido mediante $videos->listar_subestilos()

    $numero_listas = $fila->numero_listas; //Parámetros obtenidos a partir del objeto $listas
    $listas = array();
    $listas = $fila->listas;

    $coletilla = Utilidades::coletilla($votos_web); //Parámetros derivados de transformaciones de los originales de la BD
    $decada = Utilidades::decada($ano);
    $nombre_foto = Utilidades::recortar($titulo_disco);

    $inicio = strpos($enlace_youtube, "watch?v="); //Prepara los vídeos de YouTube para que se puedan visualizar embebidos
    $enlace_youtube = substr_replace($enlace_youtube, "embed/", $inicio, 8);

    if($condicion == true) $ano_disco = '('.$ano.')'; //Permite incluir el año al lado del título del disco en la página sobre las décadas
    else $ano_disco = null;

    $contador++; //Posición en la clasificación de cada canción

    require("vistas/videos.php");
}
```

Ésta es la vista HTML (`vistas/videos.php`) para cada canción, que se repite 15 veces en bucle:

```
<div class="row contenedor-youtube pt-4"><iframe class="youtube" width="575" height="323.5" src="<?=$enlace_youtube?>" allowfullscreen></iframe></div> <!--Vídeo de YouTube-->

<div class="row pt-2"> <!--Portada del disco, información relativa a la canción y sistema de votación-->

    <div class="contenedor-portada mr-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-imagen" > <!--Portada del disco-->
        <img class="portada img-fluid" src="<?=url_base?>/recursos/imagenes/<?=$decada?>/<?=$ano?>/<?=$nombre_foto?>.jpg" width="150" height="150">
    </div>

    <?php require("vistas/modales/imagen.html"); ?> <!--Modal que despliega la portada a mayor tamaño-->

    <div class="col"> <!--Información relativa a la canción y sistema de votación-->
        
        <div class="row"> <!--Información relativa a la canción (incluyendo su puesto en la clasificación)-->

            <div class="mr-3"><span class="numero" data-contador="<?=$contador?>"><?=$contador?></span></div> <!--Puesto en la clasificación-->

            <div class="col informacion ancho-min-0px"> <!--Resto de la información-->

                <div class="row ancho-max-videos"> <!--Canción y autor-->

                    <div class="puntos">

                        <span id="<?=$id_cancion?>" class="cancion font-italic"><?=$titulo_cancion?></span> de&nbsp<span id="<?=$id_autor?>"><a class="autor-recopilatorio" href="<?=$enlace_rym?>" target="_blank"><?=$nombre_autor?></a></span>

                    </div>

                </div> 

                <div class="row ancho-max-videos"> <!--Ciudad y país-->

                    <div><img class="mundo img-fluid" src="<?=url_base?>recursos/imagenes/varias/icono_mundo.png" width="18" height="18"></div>
                    <div class="col pl-2"><div class="puntos"><?=$nombre_ciudad?> (<?=$nombre_pais?>)</div></div>

                </div> 

                <div class="row ancho-max-videos"> <!--Tipo de disco, título y año (en caso de que sea la página de décadas)-->

                    <div class="puntos">
                    
                        <span>Incluida en su <?=$tipo?>&nbsp<span class="font-italic"><?=$titulo_disco?></span>&nbsp<?=$ano_disco?></span>

                    </div>

                </div> 
                
                <div class="row ancho-max-videos"> <!--Subestilos-->

                    <div class="puntos">
                    
                        <?php foreach($subestilos as $clave => $subestilo): ?>

                                <a class="boton-subestilo badge badge-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-subestilo"><span style="color: white;"><?=$subestilo?></span></a>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                    </div>

                    <?php require("modales/sugerencias.html"); ?> <!--Modal con sugerencias de canciones similares-->

                </div>
                
            </div>

        </div>
      
        <div class="d-flex row mt-1"> <!--Sistema de votación-->

            <span class="estrellas mt-3 ml-2"> <!--Estrellas-->

                <?php if($_SESSION['conectado']): ?> <!--Si el usuario está conectado-->

                    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++): ?> <!--Se crea un radiobotón de 5 unidades-->

                        <input type="radio" name="<?=$id_cancion?>" value="<?=$i?>" <?= ($i == $nota) ? 'checked data-actual="true"' : 'data-actual="false"'; ?>><i></i> <!--Todos identificados por el id de la canción pero cada uno con un valor de 1 a 5; si el valor equivale a la $nota que está registrada en la BD, el radiobotón aparece marcado y con el data-actual con valor verdadero; de lo contrario, no aparece marcado y el data-actual será falso-->

                    <?php endfor; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
                    
            </span>

            <div class="badge badge-pill badge-warning mt-3 ml-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><?=$nota_media?></div> <!--Nota media-->

            <div class="mt-3 ml-2" style="transform: translateY(2px);"><span class="font-weight-bold"><?=$votos_web?>&nbsp</span><?=$coletilla?></div> <!--Número de votos-->

            <?php if($_SESSION['conectado']): ?> <!--Si el usuario está conectado-->

                <div class="boton-recopilame mt-3 ml-auto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-agregar-canciones"><small>¡Recopílame!</small></div> <!--Se muestra el botón para añadir la canción a una lista de reproducción-->

                <?php require("vistas/modales/listas/agregar_canciones.php"); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Casi abajo del todo podéis ver el botón de acceso al modal y el `require` del modal:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['conectado']): ?> <!--Si el usuario está conectado-->

    <div class="boton-recopilame mt-3 ml-auto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-agregar-canciones"><small>¡Recopílame!</small></div> <!--Se muestra el botón para añadir la canción a una lista de reproducción-->

    <?php require("vistas/modales/listas/agregar_canciones.php"); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

El código del modal es el siguiente:

```
<!--Modal para mostrar las listas personales del usuario y acceder a ellas-->

<div id="modal-agregar-canciones" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

    <?php if($numero_listas == 0): ?> <!--En caso de que el usuario aún no haya hecho ninguna lista, el modal es de tamaño normal-->

        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">

    <?php else: ?> <!--En caso contrario, de tamaño grande-->

        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">

    <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="modal-content"> <!--Contenido-->

                <div class="modal-header justify-content-center"><h5>Tus recopilatorios <span style="color: mediumvioletred">personalizados</span></h5></div> <!--Cabecera-->

                <div class="modal-body" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                    
                    <?php if($numero_listas == 0): ?> <!--En caso de que el usuario aún no haya hecho ninguna lista, se le invita a crear una-->

                        <h6 class="text-center">Vaya, parece que aún no has creado ninguna lista con tus canciones favoritas... Si te apetece, ¡simplemente haz clic!</h6>

                    <?php else: ?>

                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            
                            <?php for($i = 1; $i <= count($listas); $i++): ?> <!--En caso contrario, se muestra una lista con los recopilatorios-->

                                <li class="list-group-item">

                                    <span class="vinetas"><?=$i?>) </span> <!--Contador-->
                                    <span class="font-italic"><?=$listas[$i - 1]->nombre_lista?> </span> <!--Título del recopilatorio-->
                                    <span style="color: mediumvioletred;"> | </span> <!--Separador-->
                                    <span>Incluye <span class="font-weight-bold"><?=$listas[$i - 1]->numero_canciones?></span><?=$listas[$i - 1]->numero_canciones == 1 ? " canción" : " canciones"?><span> <!--Número de canciones-->
                                    <span style="color: mediumvioletred;"> | </span> <!--Separador-->
                                    <span><?=$listas[$i - 1]->numero_canciones == 0 ? "Creado " : "Actualizado "?><?=Utilidades::tiempo_pasado($listas[$i - 1]->tiempo_pasado)?></span> <!--Tiempo desde la creación o última inclusión-->
                                    <a class="agregar-cancion badge badge-info"><span style="color: white;">Añádela</span></a> <!--Botón para añadir la canción-->

                                    <span class="oculto"><?=$listas[$i - 1]->id_lista_youtube?></span> <!--Etiquetas ocultas para el script de jQuery-->
                                    <span class="oculto"><?=$listas[$i - 1]->id_cancion?></span>

                                </li>

                            <?php endfor; ?>

                        </ol>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div> <!--Cuerpo-->
                
                <div class="modal-footer"> <!--Pie con el botón de acceso al menú con los recopilatorios personales-->

                    <?php if($numero_listas == 0): ?>

                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="window.location='<?=url_base?>usuarios/listas'">¡Vamos!</button>

                    <?php else: ?>

                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="window.location='<?=url_base?>usuarios/listas'">Edición en detalle</button>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

¿Por qué el modal parece que funciona con normalidad dentro del bucle pero a la hora de la verdad se queda "atascado" en el primer paso?

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo de cargar modal en un bucle no suena bien, cada modal tiene que tener un id propio, si cada boton tiene el mismo target se va a levantar siempre el primer elemento (modal) con ese id.

```
<div class="boton-recopilame mt-3 ml-auto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-agregar-canciones"><small>¡Recopílame!</small></div>
```

cambialo por algo similar a esto

```
<div class="boton-recopilame mt-3 ml-auto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-agregar-canciones<?= $clave; ?>"><small>¡Recopílame!</small></div>
```

y en el id del modal tambien.

Saludos

Comment: Genial, Álvaro, era tan sencillo como eso. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.